# Changing text while retaining the original font in a product image?

Tags: gimp, text

I have an image of a Coca-Cola bottle and would like to change the text while retaining the original font. How can I convincingly do this?

Any solutions are welcomed so long as they look convincing.

Comment: Sorry but the question makes no sense. You just asked us how to change the font while retaining the font.

Comment: Maybe the question was about how to change it to bold, italic, etc.? Or change its size, color, etc? The question should have specified these.

Comment: "How can I take a picture of a coca-cola bottle and change the **text** to my liking while retaining the original font?"  :)

Comment: This is not impossible but very difficult. I'd rather search for "3D Coca Cola model" to be modified.

Comment: Can't properly answer this question since it is on hold but you can find equivalent fonts such as [this one](http://www.dafont.com/loki-cola.font). Then you make a new logo with the font, erase the old logo, and use *Filters>Map>Map object* (to cylinder) to wrap your logo around the bottle.

Comment: @ryan can the question be released now that it makes sense?

Comment: @xenoid done. Of course this is all an educated guess at the actual meaning since Jason hasn't returned to clarify

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Coca-Cola look-alike font](http://www.dafont.com/loki-cola.font). Then

1. Erase the old logo on the original image,
2. Make a flat logo with your new text with the Text tool, using the font above
3. Use Filters>Map>Map object (to cylinder) to wrap your logo around the bottle.

[image]